# Combo dropdown list not generating data from text file using javascript jquery getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, combobox, getjson

I have a text file named country.txt. Data is stored in the said file like:

```
AF:Afghanistan
AX:Åland Islands
AL:Albania
DZ:Algeria
AS:American Samoa
AD:Andorra
AO:Angola
```

The aforesaid text file is stored in google drive.

I would like to get the aforesaid data in a combo drop down list. I have written the code as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <select id="countries" name="countries">
            <option selected="selected" value="--Please Select--">--Please Select--</option>
            $.getJSON("https://googledrive.com/host/0BxPZgr7ebTBdXzdMVWRZZ3FSSjA/country.txt", function( json ) {
               $.each(json, function(key, val) {
                  $('select[name=countries]').append( "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>" );
               });
            });  
         </select>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to get the required result with the aforesaid code.

In the list box it is showing:

```
--Please Select--
“ + val + “
```

I would like to get country name along with corresponding value as:

```
--Please Select—
Afghanistan
Åland Islands
Albania
Algeria
American Samoa
Andorra
Angola
```

I shall be highly obliged if anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: you are treating data as json but it isn't json

Comment: Added jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/sxb70m7d/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is problem in your data file it is not a `json file`.and you should be using `$.getJSON inside script tag`. try using like this once you modified your file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div>
             <select id="countries" name="countries">
                <option selected="selected" value="--Please Select--">--Please Select--</option>
                <script>
                $.getJSON("https://googledrive.com/host/0BxPZgr7ebTBdXzdMVWRZZ3FSSjA/country.txt").success( function( json ) {
                    console.log(json);
                   $.each(json, function(key, val) {
                       console.log(key,val);
                      $('select[name=countries]').append( "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>" );
                   });

                }).error(function(error){
                    console.log(error);// currently your data will come here in error.
                });
                </script>
             </select>
         </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

but if you still want to countinue with the current file.then replace the script with this:

```
<script>
                $.getJSON("https://googledrive.com/host/0BxPZgr7ebTBdXzdMVWRZZ3FSSjA/country.txt").success( function( json ) {
                    console.log(json);
                   $.each(json, function(key, val) {
                       console.log(key,val);
                      $('select[name=countries]').append( "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>" );
                   });

                }).error(function(error){
                     var x= error.responseText.split('\r\n');
                   console.log(x);
                   for(y in x){
                       var z=x[y].split(":");
                       if(z[0].length > 1){
                       $('select[name=countries]').append( "<option value='" + z[0] + "'>" + z[1] + "</option>" );
                       }
                   }
                });
```

Comment: At the outset I thank you very much for your kind reply. Your second code set has given successful result. I have lack of knowledge

Comment: if your problem is solved please accept the answer and close the topic here.@SwarupModak

Comment: At the outset I thank you very much for your kind reply. Your second code set has given successful result. I would like to use your first code set. For which I need to prepare a correct JSON file. I have lack of knowledge in creation JSON file. I have created three lines like following: ` '{"country":[' +
'{"key":"AF","val":"Afganistan" },' +
'{"key":"AX","val":"Aland Islands" },' +
'{"key":"AL","val":"Albania" }]}';`. It seems still there is a problem. Could you please help me. @user2466202 @suchit

Comment: @SwarupModak your correct json will be:{"country":[{"key":"AF","val":"Afganistan" }, {"key":"AX","val":"Aland Islands" },{"key":"AL","val":"Albania" }]}

Comment: go to this link to check your json data and modify it. http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Thanks. I have uploaded a new text file named country1.txt. The said file bearing correct JSON data. Now I have checked with your first code set, after changing the text file as 'country1.txt' instead of 'country.txt'. But the list content showing [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]. Please help.

Comment: use this in the script: <script>
                $.getJSON("https://googledrive.com/host/0BxPZgr7ebTBdXzdMVWRZZ3FSSjA/country1.txt").success( function( json ) {
                   $.each(json.country, function(key1, val1) {
                      $('select[name=countries]').append( "<option value='" + val1.key + "'>" + val1.val + "</option>" );
                   });

                }).error(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
                </script>

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working fine. I'll be pleased if you forward a message to me from your email. Thanks.

Comment: my emailId is suchitkumar007@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you put javascript code inside of html markup which cause the code to be treated as part of the markup as well. You should enclose the code between script tags and put it at the bottom of the body.